# An if statement inside a for statement, java program to calculate the grades then assign letter numbers. Scanner class please need assistance for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Can someone please help me with the if statement in a for loop, new to Java, when "999" is inserted, will break the loop. Thanks. Also, would it be good to sign a exit to the program or just exit the loop with a break statement?

```
package java_1.java;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int marks[] = new int[10];
        int i;
        float total=0,avg;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int b = 999;
        for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter Marks of Subject"+(i+1)+":");
            marks[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            total = total + marks[i];
            if(marks[i]==b)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
        
        int sum = 0;
        float average = 0.0f;
        
        // Calculating the average in for loop
        for (i=0; i<marks.length;i++) {
            sum += marks[i];
        }
        average = (float) sum / marks.length;
        
        // Printing the calculating averated value
        System.out.print("The average of he given array: " + average);
        //Calculating the average
        avg = total/10;
        System.out.printf("%n");
        System.out.print("Average student grade out of the scores is: ");
        
        // Define variables for for loop

        if(avg>=80)
        {
            System.out.print("A");
        }
        else if(avg>=60 && avg<80)
        {
            System.out.print("B");
        }
        else if(avg>=40 && avg<60)
        {
            System.out.print("C");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("D");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "when "999" is inserted, will break the loop" - yes, that's what the code does. What is your question?

Comment: Also, if your question is about the first loop, please don't include all the stuff below. It's irrelevant.

Answer (score -2):

System.exit() if your intent is to close the program
Break to close out of a loop

Answer (score -2):

> *"... would it be good to sign a exit to the program or just exit the loop with a break statement? ..."*

Utilize a *boolean* to determine if the *loop* exited early.

```java
...
int b = 999;
boolean exited = false;
for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
    ...
    if(marks[i]==b)
    {
        exited = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!exited) {
   ...
}
```